Existe-t-il une différence entre "bar à vin" et "bar à vins"?
La question est simple (c.-à-d. le sujet).
J'ai regardé ici, ici & ici et j'ai suivi les liens dans la première page, mais bien qu'ayant vu les deux phrases un peu partout et ayant appris pas mal sur les subtilités qui tracassent autant d'étrangers qui souhaitent parler la douce langue de Molière, je n'ai pas pu distinguer s'il y avait une différence ou pas entre les deux phrases.
Il me semble que c'est du kif-kif au même, mais j'aimerais avoir une réponse définitive.

Au singulier, "vin" est générique et couvre l'ensemble des vins : dans le "bar à vin", on peut boire du vin (pas un cru spécifique). C'est comme un "piège à con(s)".

@Graffito D'où la question inévitable: "Qu'est-ce qu'on peut boire dans un piège à con?".

Les deux termes existent, mais le pluriel est devenu un peu plus répandu au fil du temps.

Le sens est le même. D'ailleurs on trouve sans problème des textes qui utilisent indifféremment les deux orthographes, par exemple « Un nouveau bar à vin de 200 mètres carrés vient d’ouvrir à Bordeaux. De la musique, un bar à vins, une cave à manger, un format XXL. » ou « Les bars à vins ont fleuri en France ces dernières années […]. On comptabilise en 2021 plus de 2 000 bars à vin en France. »
Grammaticalement, un « bar à vin » est un endroit où l'on peut boire du vin (le type de boisson en général). Un « bar à vins » est un endroit qui sert plusieurs vins, c'est-à-dire plusieurs crus différents. Tous les établissements qui servent du vin proposent plus d'un vin, donc tous les bars à vin sont des bars à vins.
Il peut y avoir une exception : si, par exemple, sur un lieu de réception, il y a une table où les visiteurs peuvent obtenir un verre de vin, et une autre table pour la bière et ainsi de suite, on peut appeler le lieu de service du vin le « bar à vin ». Si ce lieu ne propose qu'un type de vin, ce ne peut pas être un « bar à vins ». Si le choix est très limité (par exemple, seulement un rouge et un blanc), et surtout si on s'attend à ce que chaque visiteur ne consomme pas plusieurs vins différents durant la réception, on aura plus tendance à laisser « bar à vin » au singulier.
Pour un commerce qui vend du vin, je pense qu'on privilégie le pluriel parce qu'il est plus vendeur. Il n'y a pas de différence de sens, mais il y a une connotation différente. Un « bar à vins » souligne le fait que le consommateur a du choix, alors qu'un « bar à vin » fait plutôt penser que boire du vin est plus important que choisir quel vin.

https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/26519945/bar-a-vin
